# Oracle BOM query returns disabled assemblies if any of its components are not

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

I have this more or less common query to get an exploded BOM with the path to the child:

```
select distinct
       LEVEL "level"
       ,sys_connect_by_path(msib.segment1, '|') as "PATH"
       ,msib2.segment1 as "CHILD ITEM"
       ,msib2.description
       ,bic.component_quantity
       ,TO_DATE(bic.IMPLEMENTATION_DATE) IMPLEMENTATION
       ,TO_DATE(bic.DISABLE_DATE)DISABLED
       ,(SELECT NAME FROM HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID = BIC.PK2_VALUE) ORGANIZATION
       ,bom.organization_id 
       ,BIC.ITEM_NUM SECUENCE
       ,bic.component_item_id CHILD_INVENTORY_ID
       , msib2.primary_uom_code UOM
from   bom.bom_components_b bic
       ,bom.bom_structures_b bom
       ,inv.mtl_system_items_b msib
       ,inv.mtl_system_items_b msib2
where  1=1
       and bic.bill_sequence_id = bom.bill_sequence_id
       and bom.assembly_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
       and bom.organization_id = msib.organization_id
       and bic.component_item_id = msib2.inventory_item_id
       and bom.organization_id = msib2.organization_id
       and bom.organization_id IN (1269)
       and bom.alternate_bom_designator is NULL
       AND bic.DISABLE_DATE IS NULL <---------------- !!!LOOK HERE!!!
       connect by nocycle prior bic.codmponent_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
```

D = the item has disabled date

```
--- EXAMPLE 0
FATHER 
   CHILD0
   CHILD1
   CHILD2
Should return:
 FATHER|CHILD0
 FATHER|CHILD1
 FATHER|CHILD2
```

--- EXAMPLE 1
FATHER 
   CHILD0 
   CHILD1 (D)
   CHILD2
Should return:
 FATHER|CHILD0
 FATHER|CHILD2

--- EXAMPLE 2
FATHER 
   CHILD0 (D)
   CHILD1 (D)
   CHILD2 (D)
Should return:
 FATHER (does not matter the assy is empty, this'd be corrected in the BOM)

--- EXAMPLE 3
FATHER (D)
   CHILD0 
   CHILD1
   CHILD2
Should return:
 NULL

With the current code if an assembly has at least one item active even if the father is not, it's loaded in the query:

```
--- EXAMPLE 4
FATHER (D)
   CHILD0 (D)
   CHILD1 (D)
   CHILD2
Returns:
 FATHER|CHILD0
 FATHER|CHILD1
 FATHER|CHILD2
Should return:
 NULL

--- EXAMPLE 5
FATHER (D)
   CHILD0
   CHILD1
   CHILD2
Returns:
 FATHER|CHILD0
 FATHER|CHILD1
 FATHER|CHILD2
Should return:
 NULL
```

How can I prevent this? This is, I need to retrieve items only if themselves or the father do NOT have disabled date. My BOMs have at most 9 levels. Thanks!

Edit: Made @mathguy modifications:

```
    select distinct
           LEVEL "level"
           ,sys_connect_by_path(msib.segment1, '|') as "PATH"
           ,msib2.segment1 as "CHILD ITEM"
           <SNIP>
    from   bom.bom_components_b bic
           ,bom.bom_structures_b bom
           ,inv.mtl_system_items_b msib
           ,inv.mtl_system_items_b msib2
    where  1=1
           and bic.bill_sequence_id = bom.bill_sequence_id
           and bom.assembly_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
           and bom.organization_id = msib.organization_id
           and bic.component_item_id = msib2.inventory_item_id
           and bom.organization_id = msib2.organization_id
           and bom.organization_id IN (1269)
           and bom.alternate_bom_designator is NULL
    START WITH msib.segment1 = 'GRANDPA' AND bic.DISABLE_DATE IS NULL 
    CONNECT BY nocycle prior bic.component_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id AND bic.DISABLE_DATE IS NULL 
           ORDER BY LEVEL,PATH ASC
```

And the query returned a lot less rows (good!) but this test case is still failing:

```
--- EXAMPLE 4
GRANDPA
  FATHER (D)
    CHILD0
    CHILD1
    CHILD2
Should return:
  GRANDPA
Returns:
  GRANDPA|FATHER|CHILD0
  GRANDPA|FATHER|CHILD1
  GRANDPA|FATHER|CHILD2
```

Perhaps this is related at how deep the hierarchy is going?

Comment: Note  - I changed one of your tags. Queries using the `CONNECT BY` mechanism are known as *hierarchical* queries. You had *recursive*-query instead; technically, that name is used for recursive `WITH` clause (also known as recursive subquery factoring or recursive CTE).

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
bic.DISABLE_DATE IS NULL
```

should not be in the `WHERE` clause, but in the `CONNECT BY` clause. What's more, since the `CONNECT BY` conditions only apply to levels 2 and above, not to the initial rows, you **also** need a `START WITH` clause, and add the same condition there.

**EDIT** - and to explain **why** that is: Your hierarchical query has a join as its starting point. When using old, Oracle-style, comma syntax for joins, some of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are seen by the parser as join conditions (and they are evaluated *before* the hierarchical step), while all the other conditions in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated only *after* the hierarchical step.

If instead the hierarchy was based on a single table (or on a subquery / inline view), then **all** the `WHERE` clause conditions would be evaluated only *after* the hierarchical step. Also, if you had used ANSI (SQL Standard) join syntax, all the `WHERE` clause conditions would be evaluated only after the hierarchical step; the conditions in the ON clause of the join, of course, would be evaluated *before* the hierarchical step.

Comment: thanks a lot! Implemented your suggestion and we are almost there. Can you take a look at my edit? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla - I can't tell without some small sample of data for testing. I suspect this may have something to do with your joins (note that in your original question, in the common language description, there were NO joins). But I can't say for sure without seeing what the data looks like.